# Avoid hardcoding messages in java classes

Tags: java, android, hard-coding

Here's a sample code:

```
toastMessage = "Data added successfully";
...  
Toast.makeText(this, toastMessage, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

In this way, users only can interact with the `English` `language`, What can I do, if I wanted to show messages like above to user base on their language preferences (e.g. German or France) in `android`.

Thanks.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/languages.html

Comment: Toast support adding strings resource value instead of String object. Even if it wouldn't, you should just take the resource via Context.getString(id) method.

Comment: I know my question was silly back then. But I think this is a community for helping each other and I don't know why some gave this question negatively. sometimes we search and try ... but in the wrong way. Note that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use strings from `string.xml` (and all other resources) in the code.

```
Toast.makeText(this, R.string.string_id, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

or for other places where you can't use id directly:

```
context.getString(R.string.string_id)
```